# remove all sheets till a given set of names using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove all sheets in the current workbook exception the list in {A2,A3, ... } and the sheet with name Summary. 
I wrote the following code

```
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range


    Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWs In wbook.Worksheets
     For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If xWs.Name <> MyCell.Value And xWs.Name <> "Summary" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next MyCell
Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

but I get an run time error which I do not know what it is.
Then, I tried to run line by line: in the first loop over "xWs.Name= Summary" there is no problem first for the second sheet I get an error at

```
If xWs.Name <> MyCell.Value And xWs.Name <> "Summary" Then
```

I know that this code is not efficient at all, because if a name matches it is still running till the end of set of names. However, I did not know how I can compare tow sets in VBA in a efficient way.
One can see in the [image: pic] the list of names in A-column.

Comment: if you have in your Range (A2, A3, ...) a string without a Sheet with that name it throws an error. Did you check to see that all worksheets names in the list do exist ?

Comment: @ShaiRado: I added a pic. All worksheets names should not occur in the list. That is the tast to keep just the sheets with the name in list

Comment: I found a solution, test the code in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to approach it a little different, you need to loop though the Range on every Sheet, once you have a match you need to raise a flag not to delete this Sheet.
Try the code below:

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim wbook As Workbook, xWs As Worksheet
Dim DeleteSheetFlag As Boolean

Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook

For Each xWs In wbook.Worksheets
    DeleteSheetFlag = True

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Select Case xWs.Name

            Case MyCell.Value, "Summary"
                DeleteSheetFlag = False
                Exit For

        End Select

    Next MyCell

    If DeleteSheetFlag Then
        xWs.Delete
    End If

Next xWs

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Shani a question: I tried to manipulate your code to get  the condition if the name of sheet contains the string in range A, then keep it otherwise remove it. some thing like 'Case **Like** MyCell.Value, "Summary"'
' DeleteSheetFlag = False'. But it is not correct in that way, do you have an idea how I can combine **case** with  **Like** ?

Comment: @maniA I suggest that you open a new post, with your question and your updated code, that way all SO users will be able to assist